# Canvas map coordinates

Tags: javascript, html, math

I want to draw exp(x) for x in [-5, 5] on a 800x800px canvas. I managed to map [-5, 5] to [0, 800] on the horizontal axis, but I'm struggling to map [exp(-5), exp(5)] to [800, 0] on the vertical axis.
Any idea on how to do that? Thanks in advance.

Comment: `I managed to map`  You've forgot to post your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a detailed example of a way to do it. `i` and `j` are canvas coordinates white `x` and `y` are the function coordinates.

Basically, mapping from `y` to `j` is similar to the inverse of mapping from `x` to `i`. But you have to subtract the result from the height since the `y` coordinate is reversed when drawing on a canvas.

```js
var c = document.querySelector('canvas');
var ctx = c.getContext('2d');
ctx.beginPath();

const width = 400;
const height = 150;

// The bounds
const minx = -5;
const maxx = 5;
const miny = Math.exp(-5);
const maxy = Math.exp(5);

ctx.moveTo(0, height);

for (let i = 0; i < width; i += width / 100) {
  // Get x from canvas coordinates
  const x = i / width * (maxx - minx) + minx;
  const y = Math.exp(x);
  // Transform y to canvas coordinates
  const j = height - (y - miny) / (maxy - miny) * height;
  // Draw in canvas coordinates
  ctx.lineTo(i, j);
}

ctx.stroke();
```

```css
canvas {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<canvas width=400 height=150></canvas>
```